# How does Django send the results of JSON to ajax in dataTables?

Tags: json

I am using `dataTables`.

I read the DB in django and created json data using json.dumps().

I received the following results:

```
"{" cust_code ":" 000027 "," cust_nm ":" abcdef "," btnid ": 1," id ": 1}
   {"cust_code": "000028", "cust_nm": "test", "btnid": 2, "id": 2}]
```

In html, I want to receive and display data from tables with ajax, but only "Loading ..." is happening.

I do not know how.

**view.py**

```
... 

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(cQuery,[cCust_nm, cDel_yn])
rows = cursor.fetchall()

result = []

keys = ('cust_nm','cust_code','id','btnid')
for row in rows:
    result.append(dict(zip(keys,row)))

json_data = json.dumps(result) 
return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type="application/json")
```

**logger.info(json_data) result** :

```
==> [{"cust_code": "000027", "cust_nm": "abcdef", "btnid": 1, "id": 1}, 
     {"cust_code": "000028", "cust_nm": "test", "btnid": 2, "id": 2}]
```

**test.html**:

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table table-bordered display 
       compact select display nowarp" id="dataTables-checkbox-scroll"></p>
  <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>cust_name</th>
     <th>cust_code</th>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>btnId</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>


  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTables-checkbox-scroll').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
              url : "{% url 'cust_findopen' %}",
              data: {
                'cust_nm': $("#cust_nm").val()
              },
              type : 'POST' ,
              datatype : 'JSON',
              dataScr : "",
            },
            "columns": [
              { data : "cust_nm" },
              { data : "cust_code" },
              { data : "id" },
              { data : "btn_id" },
            ],
            "processing": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "searching"   : false ,
            "paging"      : false,
            "info" : false ,
            success: function (row,type,val,meta) {

            },
            error: function(request, status, error){
              window.location.replace("/crms/login/") ;
            },
            fixedColumns:   {
                leftColumns: 1
            }
        } );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh !! It has been processed.

In the structure of ajax data in dataTables

{"data": [{"cust_code": "000027", "cust_nm": "abcdef", "btnid": 1, "id": 1}
  {"cust_code": "000028", "cust_nm": "test", "btnid": 2, "id": 2}]}

It was processed so that it was configured in this way, so it was simple to process.

In other words, inside the views.py source

**return_data = {"data": result};
     json_data = json.dumps (return_data)**

In this way,

**return HttpResponse (json_data, content_type = "application / json")**

, And it is normally displayed in dataTables.

Comment: Its not working. my response data structure is same as in your answer.

{"draw": 1, "recordsTotal": 15, "recordsFiltered": 15, "data": [{"log_id": 391, "iid": 391, "websessions": 14, "firstseen": "2018-12-04 12:16:48", "lastseen": "2018-12-07 18:09:44", "user_name": "teenas", "email": "teenas@xxx.com", "user_role": 2, "client_name": "xxxx", "instance_name": "xxxxx", "city": "xxx", "state": "xxxxx", "country": "xxxxx"}]}